# Closed form of $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(-\pi ^2\right)^n \cos \left(2^nb\right)}{(2 n)!}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, closed-form

> Is it possible to calculate the sum
>   $$
> \sum _{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(-\pi ^2\right)^n \cos \left(2^nb\right)}{(2 n)!}
> $$
>   in closed form?

Formal naive argument gives 
$$
\sum _{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(-\pi ^2\right)^n}{(2 n)!}\sum _{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(-b ^2\right)^m}{(2 m)!}2^{2mn}=\sum _{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(-b ^2\right)^m\cos\left(2^m\pi\right)}{(2 m)!}=\cos b-2.
$$
However, numerical calculation shows that this is wrong. For example, for $b=1/3$ http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=N%5B1%2F(Cos%5B1%2F++++3%5D+-2)Sum%5B(-%5C%5BPi%5D%5E2)%5En%2FFactorial%5B2+n%5D+Cos%5B1%2F3+2%5En%5D,+%7Bn,+0,+150%7D%5D,+35%5D

Comment: at least for $b=\pi,\pi/2...pi/2^k$ closed form solutions trivially exist

Comment: This question is similar to a previous question of mine: http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/11195/a-very-tricky-pseudo-proof-of-0-1-through-series-and-integrals. Assuming that the dominated convergence theorem holds when it does not, we may prove $0=1$. The situation, here, is just the same.

Comment: $$
\small S=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{\pi^{2n}\cos(b 2^n)}{(2n)!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\pi^{4n}\cos(b 4^n)}{(4n)!}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\pi^{4n+2}\cos(2b 4^n)}{(4n+2)!}=S_1-S_2\\
\small |\cos(\theta)|\le 1 \Rightarrow |S_1|\le\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\pi^{4n}}{(4n)!}=1/2\cosh(\pi)-1/2 \quad\&\quad\\
\small |S_2|\le\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\pi^{4n+2}}{(4n+2)!}=1/2\cosh(\pi)+1/2\Rightarrow \color{red}{|S|\le\cosh(\pi)}
$$
However, applying the changing sum on $S_1$ is more clear why it is wrong to do so,
$\{\space |S_1|\le 1/2\cosh(\pi)-1/2 \space\}$ converge, but:

Comment: For simplicity's sake, let $b=1$:
$$
\small \text{converge }S_1=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\pi^{4n}\cos(4^n)}{(4n)!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{\pi^{4n}}{(4n)!}\left[\frac{4^{4mn}}{(4m)!}-\frac{4^{4mn+2n}}{(4m+2)!}\right]\color{red}{\ne}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\pi^{4n}}{(4n)!}\left[\frac{4^{4mn}}{(4m)!}-\frac{4^{4mn+2n}}{(4m+2)!}\right]\\
\small =1/2\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\left[\frac{\cos(\pi 4^m)}{(4m)!}-\frac{\cos(2\pi 4^m)}{(4m+2)!}\right] + 1/2\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\left[\frac{\cosh(\pi 4^m)}{(4m)!}-\frac{\cosh(2\pi 4^m)}{(4m+2)!}\right]\text{ diverge}
$$

Comment: Nevertheless, the series is even and a rapid convergent, resulting-in showing a kind of periodicity behavior (https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Z565.png).
$$
\small f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{\pi^{2n}\cos(x 2^n)}{(2n)!}\Rightarrow\left\{f(x)=f(-x)\,,\space f(x)\approx \sum_{n=0}^{9}(-1)^n\frac{\pi^{2n}\cos(x 2^n)}{(2n)!}\Rightarrow f(x)\approx f(x+2\pi)\right\}
$$
Without excluding the possibility of a closed-form causes this periodic behavior.